# dataGridview1.refresh doesn't work when bound to a pure dataTable (no Database behind)

Tags: c#, winforms

I have a datatable which I bound programmatically to dataGridview1

```
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        dataTable = new DataTable();            
        dataTable.Columns.Add("name");

        this.dataGridView1.DataSource = dataTable;
```

Then in some event handler I add new row in dataTable and do a refresh which doesn't work : grid stays empty!

```
        DataRow dataRow = dataTable.NewRow();
        dataRow["name"] = "John";

        dataGridView1.Refresh();
```

I read here http://objectmix.com/dotnet/92001-datagridview-doesnt-refresh.html to use RaiseListChangedEvents but I can't see how since I have no bindingsource as far as I can see.

Am I obliged to use another control BindingSource just to do that pretty basic functionality ? What's the use of Refresh method for the GridView then ?

Note: I can add to a simple list with no problem.

Update: for the context, I am capturing the text in clipboard (that part works so no problem) and just put it in the grid. I have tried the invoke method as suggested but it still doesn't work:

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    public delegate void DelRefresh();


    private ClipboardSpy cps;
    private DataTable dataTable;

    public override void Refresh()
    {
        dataGridView1.DataSource = dataTable;
    }

    public Main()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        cps = new ClipboardSpy(this);
        cps.ClipboardChanged += new EventHandler(cps_ClipboardChanged);

        dataTable = new DataTable();            
        dataTable.Columns.Add("Url");

        this.dataGridView1.DataSource = dataTable;


    }

    void cps_ClipboardChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        String clipboardText = cps.GetClipboardData();
        DataRow dataRow = dataTable.NewRow();
        dataRow["Url"] = clipboardText;


        dataGridView1.Invoke(new DelRefresh(Refresh));


        //listBox1.Items.Add(string.Format("{0:HH:mm:ss} " + clipboardText, DateTime.Now));
        //listBox1.SelectedIndex = listBox1.Items.Count - 1;
    }
```

}

Comment: Read my question on the accepted post?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`UPDATE`

You neet to add

```
datatTable.add(dataRow);
```

after setting the name property or the row is not added to the table.

NewRow only creates a row object matching the table, it does not add it to the table.

Comment: I don't use BindingSource control as datasource for my gridview. RaiseListChangeEvents  is a prop of BindingSource. Why refresh doesn't work as expected ?

Answer (score 1):

actually, because the datatable is bound to your datagridview, all changes to the datatable should appear immediately in the datagridview.

What could be the reason why your view is not updating, is that you are making the changes to the datatable in a different thread than the UI thread.

What you need to do is, to call something like

```
dataGridView1.Invoke(new DelRefresh(Refresh));
```

with

```
public delegate void DelRefresh();

public void Refresh()
{
      dataGridView1.DataSource = dataTable
}
```

which should make it work.

Comment: Hello was a great idea so I tried it see my updated source code above with the full context (capturing a clipboard text). But still doesn't work.

Comment: Stupidly it was due to the fact that I used Newrow but didn't add row to datatable but your trick will be usefull if I need to use thread one day so thanks :)

Comment: Why was this selected as the accepted answer when I have listed that you missed addrow in my post melow about an hour before your comment  ;)

Answer (score 0):

try

Instead of

```
dataGridView1.Refresh();
```

try

```
dataGridView1.DataSource = dataTable
```